# How to return an array in a function in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code

```
*int my_arr(int a) {
    int arr[a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I keep getting errors

Comment: It's impossible to return an array from a function in C++. It's also not legal to declare an array with a variable size in C++. Life is much easier if you use a `std::vector` instead. Both of those things are legal for vectors.

Comment: "_How to return an array..."_ - Use either [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) .

Comment: If you changed `*int` to `int*` your code would (perhaps) compile, but it would still be bugged, and you are still not returning an array, you would be returning a pointer. And that pointer would be pointing at an array which no longer existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return an array in cpp. Instead use vectors.

```
vector<int> my_arr(int a) {
    vector<int> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        arr.push_back(input);  // to push elements into vector
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Your reasonable answer has the Check mark. I'm pretty sure OP is still struggling.

Comment: `arr` is a somewhat misleading name for a `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, if you reserve `a` size for your vector when you create it, you can read directly into it's elements. `std::vector<int> vec(a); for (auto &i : vec) { std::cin >> i; }`